# Spring 5 JdbcTemplate cannot reuse PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, prepared-statement, spring-jdbc

One simple optimization for SQL is the reuse of prepared statements.  You incur the parsing cost once and can then reuse the `PreparedStatement` object within a loop, just changing the parameters as needed.  This is clearly documented in [Oracle's JDBC tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#supply_values_ps) and many other places.

Spring 5 when using `JdbcTemplate` seems to make this impossible.  All `JdbcTemplate` query and update methods that deal with `PreparedStatementCreator`s funnel down to one `execute` method.  Here's the code of that method in its entirety.

```
public <T> T execute(PreparedStatementCreator psc, PreparedStatementCallback<T> action)
        throws DataAccessException {

    Assert.notNull(psc, "PreparedStatementCreator must not be null");
    Assert.notNull(action, "Callback object must not be null");
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        String sql = getSql(psc);
        logger.debug("Executing prepared SQL statement" + (sql != null ? " [" + sql + "]" : ""));
    }

    Connection con = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(obtainDataSource());
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        ps = psc.createPreparedStatement(con);
        applyStatementSettings(ps);
        T result = action.doInPreparedStatement(ps);
        handleWarnings(ps);
        return result;
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        // Release Connection early, to avoid potential connection pool deadlock
        // in the case when the exception translator hasn't been initialized yet.
        if (psc instanceof ParameterDisposer) {
            ((ParameterDisposer) psc).cleanupParameters();
        }
        String sql = getSql(psc);
        psc = null;
        JdbcUtils.closeStatement(ps);
        ps = null;
        DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
        con = null;
        throw translateException("PreparedStatementCallback", sql, ex);
    }
    finally {
        if (psc instanceof ParameterDisposer) {
            ((ParameterDisposer) psc).cleanupParameters();
        }
        JdbcUtils.closeStatement(ps);
        DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
    }
}
```

The "interesting" bit is in the `finally` block:

```
        JdbcUtils.closeStatement(ps);
```

This makes it completely impossible to reuse a prepared statement with JdbcTemplate.

It's been a long time (5 years) since I've had occasion to work with Spring JDBC, but I don't recall this ever being a problem.  I worked on a large SQL backend with literally hundreds of prepared statements and I clearly remember not having to re-prepare them for every execution.

What I want to do is this:

```
private static final String sqlGetPDFFile = "select id,root_dir,file_path,file_time,file_size from PDFFile where digest=?";
private PreparedStatement psGetPDFFile;

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException
{
    Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
    psGetPDFFile = con.prepareStatement(sqlGetPDFFile);
    this.tmpl = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
...
...
    List<PDFFile> files = 
        tmpl.query(
            
            // PreparedStatementCreator
            c -> { 
                psGetPDFFile.setBytes(1, fileDigest); 
                return psGetPDFFile; 
            },

            // RowMapper
            (rs, n)-> 
            {
                long        id          = rs.getLong(1);
                Path        rootDir     = Paths.get(rs.getString(2));
                Path        filePath    = Paths.get(rs.getString(3));
                FileTime    fileTime    = FileTime.from(rs.getTimestamp(4).toInstant());
                long        fileSize    = rs.getLong(5);
                return new PDFFile(id,fileDigest,rootDir,filePath,fileTime,fileSize);
            }
            );
```

But of course this fails the second time because of the hardcoded statement close call.

The question: Assuming I want to continue using Spring JDBC, what is the correct way to reuse prepared statements?

Also, if anyone knows why Spring does this (i.e. there's a good reason for it) I'd like to know.

Comment: Of course you can, it's called **batch processing**, and you do it by calling one of the `batchUpdate()` methods on the `JdbcTemplate`. Web search for [`JdbcTemplate batch`](https://www.google.com/search?q=JdbcTemplate+batch) will find you gazillions of examples.

Comment: That's not exactly what I had in mind.  It's not a question of a large batch, this is in a program with a UI. Are you saying the driving factor here is that in a non-batch scenario the cost of preparing a statement isn't enough to worry about?

Comment: Correct. Some JDBC drivers will cache prepared SQL statements for re-use, so when you re-prepare the SQL, it doesn't have to send it to the database server for parsing again. E.g. [PostgreSQL](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html) has connection properties `prepareThreshold` (default: 5), `preparedStatementCacheQueries` (default: 256), and `preparedStatementCacheSizeMiB` (default: 5). The first *"determines the number of `PreparedStatement` executions required before switching over to use **server side prepared statements**"*.

Comment: The lack of reuse of PreparedStatement is not unique for JdbcTemplate. The most probable reason is that PreparedStatement **must** be implemented to cover *bind variables* but the reuse will introduce a possible problems with the cursor leak (aka *too many cursors open*). Further such JDBC Frameworks are still “better” than ORM and not much “worst” (due to cursor caching) than plain JDBC there is not much pressure to change something.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber That seems like the best answer, please post it as an answer instead of a comment. And yes, I find that `JdbcTemplate` strikes the right balance between ease of use and functionality. ORM is too heavyweight and plain JDBC is a pain :-)